# How to pipe stdin into a perl script that is looking for input as the only parameter?

Tags: perl, pipe, stdin

This question was necessitated out of laziness on my part, because I have dozens of scripts that are executed in the simple structure:

```
perl my_script.pl my_input_file
```

...and the output is printed to stdout. However, now I realize that I have certain situation in which I would like to pipe input into these scripts. So, something like this:

```
perl my_script.pl my_input_file | perl my_next_script.pl | perl third_script.pl > output
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this without recoding all of my scripts to accept stdin instead of a user-defined input file? My scripts look for the filename by a statement like this:

```
open(INPUT,$ARGV[0]) || die("Can't open the input file");
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `-` as filename

```
perl my_script.pl my_input_file | perl my_next_script.pl - | perl third_script.pl - > output
```

Answer (score 11):

[mpapec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223226/mpapec) has provided the simplest solution. I would like to recommend the diamond operator: `<>`.

In a script where you would do

```
open my $fh, "<", $ARGV[0] or die $!;
while (<$fh>) { 
    ...
```

You can use the diamond operator to replace most of that code

```
while (<>) {
    ...
```

The file handle name will be `ARGV` if you use argument file names, or `STDIN` if not. The file name will be found in `$ARGV`.

This operator invokes a behaviour where Perl looks for input either from file name arguments, or from standard input.

Which means that whether you do

```
inputpipe | script.pl
```

or

```
script.pl inputfile.txt
```

The diamond operator will take the input just fine.

Note: Your `open` statement is dangerous. You should use three argument open with explicit mode, and lexical file handle. The `die` statement connected to it should contain the error variable `$!` to provide information about why the open failed.

Comment: A complication arises if you want your Perl script to both accept standard input and also arguments, for example `echo "some input" | perl my-script.pl <arg1> <arg2> etc.`. In that case the `while(<>) {...}` will try to act on the argument(s), and not the standard input. In such case you nee to explicitly tell Perl to iterate over STDIN like so, `while(<STDIN>) {...}` to clear up ambiguity.

Comment: It might be worth explaining why the 2-argument version of the `open` statement is dangerous. One can maliciously/recklessly pass arguments like: `perl my_script.pl '>some-important-file-want-to-destroy'` to a script with `open(INPUT,$ARGV[0])`. Notice the `>` in front of file name, which opens the file for output. The 3-argument version of `open` prevents against this attack because it explicitly specifies the mode to open the file in (I.e. `<` to read from file) as the second argument.

Comment: @JoseQuijada Not only that, but it allows you to run arbitrary commands in the shell. But that is beyond the scope of the question anyway.